# How do I unselect the notify subscribers options when Uploading a video via Youtube API JAVA

Tags: java, api, youtube

This can be found in the advanced settings when uploading a video manually through the youtube website. Im trying to turn off notifications for subscribers.

[image of settings on youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TenAE.png)

Is there a setting or option I need to change, Im using the sample code supplied by google.

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java

Also JAVA please Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but I had the same question.

You can set this parameter against the [YouTube.Videos.Insert](http://javadox.com/com.google.apis/google-api-services-youtube/v3-rev90-1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.Videos.Insert.html) class, using the [setNotifySubscribers(boolean)](http://javadox.com/com.google.apis/google-api-services-youtube/v3-rev90-1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.Videos.Insert.html#setNotifySubscribers(java.lang.Boolean)) method

```
YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();
YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsertRequest = 
                youtube.videos().insert("snippet,status", video, mediaContent);
videoInsertRequest.setNotifySubscribers(null);
Video response = videosInsertRequest.execute();
```